# Query by part of string in custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to query for a string if present in a custom field.

e.g. Within the custom field I have a value like: `Milano romani` and If I have a string **Milano** from `GET`, I should find it. But the following gives me all posts even if no string match in the custom field

```
<?php
    $myTerm = $_GET['cityName']; 

    $catIds = array();

    $args = get_posts( 
        array( 
            'post_type'      => 'post', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'meta_query'     => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'usp-custom-23',
                    'value'   => $myTerm,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            ) 
        ) 
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            $id = get_the_ID();
            array_push($catIds, $id);
        }
        $catIds = implode( ", ", $catIds );

        if(count($catIds) > 0){
            $arrayFUllCity = "fullCity";
        } else {
            $arrayFUllCity = "empty";
        }
    }
        var_dump($catIds);
?>
```

Comment: Please, rephrase "IN the custom fieldI have: Milano romani If I GET Milano, I should find it".

Comment: @bart sorry i didn't understand

Comment: Re-write that phrase, it's unclear.

Comment: @bart check now please

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Try to use "%$myTerm%" this would tell MySQL to do a full text search.

Comment: @bart I still get no results array(0) { }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183989/discussion-between-rob-m-and-bart).